# How can I combine the two select queries on the same table horizontally in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, join, pivot, subquery, inner-join

everyone. I am a beginner of Postgresql. Recently I met with one question. 
I have one table named 'sales'.

```
create table sales
    (
        cust    varchar(20),
        prod    varchar(20),
        day integer,
        month   integer,
        year    integer,
        state   char(2),
        quant   integer
    );
insert into sales values ('Bloom', 'Pepsi', 2, 12, 2001, 'NY', 4232);
insert into sales values ('Knuth', 'Bread', 23, 5, 2005, 'PA', 4167);
insert into sales values ('Emily', 'Pepsi', 22, 1, 2006, 'CT', 4404);
insert into sales values ('Emily', 'Fruits', 11, 1, 2000, 'NJ', 4369);
insert into sales values ('Helen', 'Milk', 7, 11, 2006, 'CT', 210);
insert into sales values ('Emily', 'Soap', 2, 4, 2002, 'CT', 2549);
insert into sales values ('Bloom', 'Eggs', 30, 11, 2000, 'NJ', 559);
```

....
There are 498 rows in total.
Here is the overview of this table:

[image]

Now I want to compute the maximum and minimum sales quantities for each product, along with their corresponding customer (who purchased the product), dates (i.e., dates of those maximum and minimum sales quantities) and the state in which the sale transaction took place. 
And the average sales quantity for the corresponding products.

The combined one should be like this:

[image]

It should have 10 rows because there are 10 distinct products in total.

I have tried:

```
select prod,
       max(quant),
       cust as MAX_CUST
from sales
group by prod;
```

but it returned an error and said the cust should be in the group by. But I only want to classify by the type of product.

What's more, how can I horizontally combine the **max_q and its customer, date, state** with **min_q and its customer, date, state** and also the **AVG_Q** by their **product name**? 
I feel really confused!

Comment: For future questions: sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use analytic function ROW_NUMBER to rank records by increasing/decreasing sales for each product in a subquery, and then do conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    prod product,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN quant END) max_quant,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN cust END) max_cust,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN TO_DATE(year || '-' || month || '-' || day, 'YYYY-MM-DD') END) max_date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN state END) max_state,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN quant END) min_quant,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN cust END) min_cust,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN TO_DATE(year || '-' || month || '-' || day, 'YYYY-MM-DD') END) min_date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN state END) min_state,
    avg_quant
FROM (
    SELECT
        s.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY prod ORDER BY quant) rn1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY prod ORDER BY quant DESC) rn2,
        AVG(quant) OVER(PARTITION BY prod) avg_quant
    FROM sales s
) x
WHERE rn1 = 1 OR rn2 = 1
GROUP BY prod, avg_quant
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help!!! I removed the "s." from the "s.*" and added a round()to the avg(quant) and it finally output the result I wanted. It's just can you tell me why the "s.*" won't work and what type of syntax this is????

Comment: @WikizVito: `s` is just an alias for the `sales` table. I just updated the query (alias was not declared), it should work fine as it is now.

Comment: All right, thanks! And why can't I get the integer of the avg(quant) by using round( )?

Comment: @WikizVito: `round()` will work as expected, like so: `ROUND(AVG(quant) OVER(PARTITION BY prod)) avg_quant`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right! I made a mistake about the position of the right parenthesis. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome @WikizVito!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278903/how-can-i-remove-the-null-values-and-make-it-to-10-rows-in-postgresql

Comment: can you help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280347/how-to-show-the-maximum-number-for-each-combination-of-customer-and-product-in-a

Answer (score 1):

With two aggregate function (min, max) applied on a column and selecting respective row is not that straight forward. if u wanted only one aggregate function u could do something like example below with dense rank (window function).

```
SELECT prod, quant cust,
    dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY prod ORDER BY quant DESC) AS c_rank
FROM sales WHERE c_rank < 2;
```

this will give you rows for a product with maximum `quant`. you can do same for minimum quant. it will more complicated to do both in same query, you can do it in simple way of creating on the fly tables for each case and joining them as show below.

```
with max_quant as (
SELECT prod, quant cust,
    dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY prod ORDER BY quant DESC) AS c_rank
FROM sales WHERE c_rank < 2
),
min_quant as (
SELECT prod, quant cust,
    dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY prod ORDER BY quant DESC) AS c_rank
FROM sales WHERE c_rank < 2
),
avg_quant as (
select prod, avg(quant) as avg_quant from sales group by prod
)

select mx.prod, mx.quant, mx.cust, mn.quant, mn.cust, ag.avg_quant
from max_quant mx 
join min_quant mn on mn.prod = mx.prod
join avg_quant ag on ag.prod = mx.prod;
```

you cant use a `group by` to select min/max here as you want to get the complete row for the min/max value of quant which is not possible directly with `group by`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help first. I ran the 
`SELECT prod, quant cust
    dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY prod ORDER BY quant DESC) AS c_rank
FROM sales WHERE c_rank < 2;`
But still, it says the syntax mistake is around the dense_rank()...

Comment: There is a comma missing between selected fields. Updated query will be ```SELECT prod, quant ,cust ,dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY prod ORDER BY quant DESC) AS c_rank FROM sales WHERE c_rank < 2;```